# Limit points in a $T_1$ Space

Tags: general-topology

Because we are working in a $T_1$, if $\mathcal{O}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ not containing $y$, then there exists open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ containing $x$ and $y$, respectively, but not containing the other point. Hence, $\mathcal{O} \cap U \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ is an open set containing $x$ but not containing $y$.

Now that that has been said, we can state the problem.

> Let $A$ be an infinite subset of a $T_1$ space, and let $x$ be a limit point of $A$. Prove that every open neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Then there exists $a_1 \in \mathcal{O} \cap (A-\{x\})$. By the observation made above, we can find an open neighborhood $\mathcal{O}_2$ of $x$ that doesn't contain $a_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{O}$. Hence, there exists $a_2 \in \mathcal{O}_2 \cap (A-\{x,a_1\})$. Continuing this process, we obtain an infinite sequence $(a_n)$ of distinct points in $A$, since $a_n \in \mathcal{O}_n \cap (A-\{x,a_1,...,a_{n-1}\})$, such that $a_n$ is in $\mathcal{O}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thereby proving that $\mathcal{O}$ contains an infinite number of points in $A$.

How does this sound? It seems little shaky; perhaps it could be made slightly more rigorous. In particular, I don't like the phrase "continuing this process."

**EDIT:**

I didn't fully read your answer, tattwamasi amrutam, only that you proved it by contradiction, so I came up with a variant that I am hoping you (or anyone quite frankly) will critique. Let $x$ be a limit point of $A$, and $\mathcal{O}$ an open set containing $x$. However, by way of contradiction, suppose that $\mathcal{O} \cap (A - \{x\}) = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$ is finite. By the above remark, we can find $\mathcal{O}_{i} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{i}$ contains $x$ but does not contain $a_k$. Then $\cap \mathcal{O}_i \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ is an open set, because it is a finite union, containing $x$ but cannot any $a_k$. Since $x$ is a limit point, this newly constructed open set must intersect $A-\{x\}$ at $a \neq a_1,...,a_n$. But $\cap \mathcal{O}_i \subseteq \mathcal{O}$, implying that $\mathcal{O}$ contains an extra point of $A$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: A small re-wording:  You have shown that (1):  $O\cap (A$ \ $\{x\})$ is not empty, and (2):  For all $n\in \mathbb N,$  if  $\{a_1,...,a_n\}\subset  O\cap (A$ \ $ \{x\})$ then there exists $a_{n+1} \in O \cap (A$  \ $ \{x\})$ with $a_{n+1}\not \in \{a_1,...,,a_n\}. $  So the non-empty set $O\cap (A$ \  $\{x\})$ cannot be equal to any finite set $\{a_1,...,a_n\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right. You can make it more rigorous by arguing the contrary:

Suppose that there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{O}$ of $x$, such that $\mathcal{O} \cap A$ is finite. Let $a_1,\ldots a_k$ be the points which lie in the intersection $\mathcal{O} \cap A$. Then for each $a_i$, there exists open neighborhoods $U_{x,i},V_{x,i}$ containing $x$ and $a_i$ respectively such that $U_{x,i} \cap V_{x,i}=\phi$. Let $U_x=\cap_{i=1}^kU_{x,i}$.Then $U_x \cap \mathcal{O}$ is open, contains $x$. But $(U_x \cap \mathcal{O}) \cap A=\phi$ which means that we have found a neighborhood of $x$ whose intersection with $A$ is empty. This is a violation of the definition of limit point.

Comment: I am not sure whether this undermines your proof, but in a $T_1$ space I don't believe we necessarily have that $U_{x,i} \cap V_{x,i}=\phi$. 
I didn't fully read your answer when I was first notified that you had answered my question, only that you proved it by contradiction, so I came up with a variant that I am hoping you will critique.